# Vagrant Puppet cannot find my vagrant node

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I have configured my vm.hostname to "vagrant-development".

My puppet is supposed to look for a vagrant node name "vagrant-development".

I am new to puppet and vagrant. But have been through this doc http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/puppet_agent.html and have a configured Vagrantfile.

I don't understand why do I keep running into

```
debug: Executing '/usr/bin/perl /usr/local/abc/components/kvagrant/bin/enc.pl    /vagrant/.enc/vagrant-development vagrant-development'
debug: Empty response for vagrant-development from exec terminus
Could not run: Could not find node vagrant-development
```

How do I make puppet find the vagrant node?

Comment: So where is your `Vagrantfile`?

Comment: and can you confirm if the puppet version is updated or not? In Vagrant, if you didn't update the repo, the puppet version will still be 2.7.x

Comment: my vagrantfile is in the same dir. And yes my puppet version is 2.7.20

Comment: so update the puppet in vagrant http://blog.doismellburning.co.uk/2013/01/19/upgrading-puppet-in-vagrant-boxes/, should fix your issue.

Comment: If you are new to both puppet and vagrant, then you should start with the 'puppet apply' provisioner, not 'puppet agent'.